# Update method not doing anything to a document - can't understand why

Tags: dart

I'm a total beginner working through an entry-level university course on data handling. I've been tasked with building a simple database app that the user can add movies to and then mark them "watched". I have a "watch a movie" function (source below) that needs to prompt the user for the name of the movie and then mark that particular movie as "watched". The function receives a movie collection from a database as its single parameter, and the collection only contains the name and watched status for each movie.

Now what happens is the update method on the last line doesn't do anything, and I can't figure out why. I've tested it by including a print command right after the update command, but the document is unchanged. I even tried updating the name of the movie at the same time, but no change.

Any ideas?

```
watch(collection) async {
  print('Name of the movie?');
  var name = stdin.readLineSync();

  var terms = Query(filter: ValueFilter({'name': name}));
  var results = await collection.search(query: terms);
  var documents = results.snapshots;

  for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
    var data = documents[i].data;
    var document = documents[i].document;
    document.update(data: {'name': data['name'], 'watched': true});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had help and managed to solve this. I don't know why, but the ValueFilter needed a MapFilter around it, i.e.

```
var haku = Query(filter: MapFilter({'nimi': ValueFilter(nimi)}));
```

It works now, but if anyone could explain why, I'd appreciate it. :D